# WSO2 Distributed setup - no access to API via Gateway

Tags: wso2, gateway

I read a lot of information about this topic but I have no answer.

I have 3 servers with following components

1. server1 - WSO2 IS + OpenLDAP
2. server2 - WSO2 Gateway
3. server3 - Publisher + Store

All of theese servers working with LDAP and I have no problems to login to IS, Gateway, publisher and store with my Ldap login.

In Publisher config file I wrote Gateway server2 but when I publish new test API I have access to this API (`server3:8243/ddd/v1/aaa`), but via gateway I have no access `https://server2:8243/ddd/v1/aaa` and I got an Error 404.

How I need to configure my WSO2 Publisher or Gateway.

P.S. At this moment I have no genereated ssl keys in a keystore. Can you tell me how to resolve this problem for testing my TEST API?

Comment: Did you configure your Gateway environments in api-manager.xml in your publisher node?

Comment: Have configured the gateway URLs correctly in your publisher node?
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Deploying+WSO2+API-M+in+a+Distributed+Setup#DeployingWSO2API-MinaDistributedSetup-Step6.3-ConfigureandstarttheAPIPublisher

Comment: Dear friend, the api-manager.xml is configured and see to the gateway node.

Comment: How many config lines i need to edit for connect Publisher with Gateway?. I saw official manual and there are - 3-5 line for Gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you publish an API from the publisher, it pushes the Synapse artifact of the API to the gateway node. But in your case, as you haven't changed any configuration in Publisher/Store node, it points to the server itself.

You can edit the server 3 and point server 2 which is your gateway node. Edit the api-manager.xml file in APIM/repository/conf location.

```
<APIGateway>
   <Environments>
       <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
            <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
            <Description>This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic.</Description>          
            <ServerURL>https://[API-Gateway-Host-or-IP]:9443/services/</ServerURL>
            <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
            <Password>${admin.password}</Password>          
            <GatewayEndpoint>http://[API-Gateway-Host]:8280,https://[API-Gateway-Host]:8243</GatewayEndpoint>
       </Environment>
   </Environments>
</APIGateway>
```

Comment: Good afternoon. I checked and resolve this problem with publish API. And I got another trouble with ssl handshake. I created 3 jks store on each servers and import open keys to the truststore on each server. Maybe it's not required but tell me please: How is correctly make an ssl handshake between IS, GATEWAY and PUBLISHER servers? Thx